-layoutSubtreeIfNeeded message on Mac OS 12.7.6, GNU Emacs 28.1
I get the following message in Terminal on a Mac OS 12.7.6 (Monterey) after opening GNU Emacs 28.1:
2024-10-22 10:15:40.274 Emacs-x86_64-10_14[58913:34187688] It's not legal to call -layoutSubtreeIfNeeded on a view which is already being laid out.  If you are implementing the view's -layout method, you can call -[super layout] instead. Break on void _NSDetectedLayoutRecursion(void) to debug.  This will be logged only once.  This may break in the future.
What is the meaning of this message and how can I stop it?

Ignore it.
This is a warning from AppKit and relates to an internal change that happened between Big Sur and Monterey. You can see related discussions:
Emacs related:
https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/tf9i1p/gnu_emacs_for_mac_os_x_warning_message_after/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70781126/when-i-edit-a-file-with-emacs-i-get-a-strange-error-how-do-i-fix-this
https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=53481
wxWidgets:
https://groups.google.com/g/wx-dev/c/UIglTkPuRss
I'm sure your favorite search engine can help you find more examples. If you truly can't stand to see it, redirect stderr to /dev/null when starting Emacs, or update it to the current version.
